# Translation of sentences

Tags: american-english, british-english, sentence-meaning

> The US death toll from the coronavirus climbed to 12 on Thursday, with all but one of the victims in the north-western US state of Washington.

What does it mean: 11 dead in Washington Or just 1 one dead there?

Comment: All the victims, except one, **being from** ... Washington. The use of the preposition *in* is odd here.

Answer (score -1):

It means 11 died there. 
It can be parsed as follows.
All (12) but one (-1) of the victims in (so the total = 11 are in) the north-western US state of Washington.

All of the peaches on the tree but (not) the one I picked yesterday were eaten by bats last night.

Comment: See also my comment at OP.